# How do I create a server for Minecraft Pocket Edition v0.1.11?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't seem to create a server because when I search it only shows answers for other versions or iPhones only. How do I make a server for this version?

Comment: What device are you using?

Answer (score -2):

There is a server software called PocketMine, which once installed on your computer can host a server for you and your friends to connect to. PocketMine also has an API which allows developers to create plugins, which you can download to change how the server works.

The website is https://www.pocketmine.net/ which has links to downloads for the latest stable/beta/development downloads with installation guides.

Stack Exchange Gaming Blog also did an post on how to setup and configure Pocket Mine http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2014/06/how-to-create-a-minecraft-pe-server/

Comment: Please include more info as website can go down.

Comment: How, exactly, does one use this software to do what the asker wants?

Comment: @Frank yes-ish. The question isn't clear.

Comment: @ardaozkal I'm not asking if it does what the asker wants.  I'm asking him to tell us *how* to use the software to do what the asker wants.  If you're recommending a certain product, it's only the first part in answering a question.